# StreamReader row and line delimiters

Tags: c#, arrays, tokenize, delimiter, streamreader

I am trying to figure out how to tokenize a StreamReader of a text file. I have been able to separate the lines, but now I am trying to figure out how to break down those lines by a tab delimiter as well. This is what I have so far.

```
string readContents;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"File.txt"))
{
    readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I don't understand. If every line has columns delimited by tabs then the same method that splits your lines at the carriage return can split a single line at the tab character and render an array of strings from your line

Comment: Why would you call `ReadToEnd()` if you want to split by line breaks? Calling `ReadLine()` will read a single line you can iterate or split by tabs or whatever.

Comment: @DourHighArch That's a good point. I recall running into an issue previously, and then just jumped right over to this solution. I'll probably end up switching back over to that one soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string readContents;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"File.txt"))
{
    readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
         string[] lines2 = s.Split('\t');
         foreach (string s2 in lines2)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(s2);
         }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

not really sure if that is what you want, but... it breaks (tab) the already broken (return) lines

Answer (score 2):

Just call `Split()` on each of the lines and keep them in a List.  If you need an array you can always call `ToArray()` on the list:

```
string readContents;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"File.txt"))
{
    readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    string[] lines = readContents.Split('\r');
    List<string> pieces = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in lines)
    {
        pieces.AddRange(s.Split('\t'));
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```